A cartoon with oddball superheroes, one made out of rope
This is the question of my lifetime, I've always been looking for the right time and place to ask, this seems to be the time and it certainly seems to be the place. 
I was born in 1992 and I know that I was a kid when I saw this.
I think it was aired on FoxKids before they changed their name to Jetix.
The only thing I recall vividly is this superhero or mutant that is made out of rope, there may have been a crab-man involved as well.
It's more likely to be from a certain episode than an entire series.. If anyone can pinpoint this I would be impressed

Could it be the "Earthworm Jim" cartoon which aired in 1995-1996 (which would fit your time frame). It only had two seasons. Earthworm Jim is a mutant Earthworm in a robotic superhero suit. I could see where he might be mistaken for a Superhero made of rope.

@JoshuaA If you posted that as an answer, I'd definitely give you a thumbs up! Include a picture too.

How about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creepy_Crawlers_(TV_series)


Hope this is what you are looking for.

That is correct!

Great, Happy to help
